# How to Create the Filters by using the Product options in the CS Cart

Tags: javascript, php, cs-cart

I am new to CS cart, i want to create the filters(size, colour)  by using the Products Options, but I don't see the any options in the back end of the Cs-cart to create the Filters on the Product options. Just I am seeing only option to create filters using the features. anybody can help me Please, How to create the Filters on the product options.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible with a standard Cs-Cart installation. There are addons that can provide this functionality. You can browse them at: http://marketplace.cs-cart.com/